# Sorting by foreign table value with Kohana ORM

Tags: mysql, orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Is there any way to sort (or order by) in ORM by using a value from a foreign table?

Can you do something like the following:

```
ORM::factory("table")->order_by("table.foregin_table.column" , "ASC")
```

Or do you have to use some regular MySQL and join the tables together old school?

Comment: `orm::factory("table")->with("table2")->order_by("table2.column" , "ASC")` should work (not tested). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 6):

Of course it's possible. For example I have two tables with pictures and votes with relation one to many. Let's say I want to sort pictures by number of votes to get the most popular pictures. It will this:

```
$pictures = ORM::factory('picture')
    ->select(array('COUNT("picture_votes.id")', 'votes'))
    ->join('picture_votes','left')
    ->on('picture_votes.picture_id','=','pictures.id')
    ->group_by('pictures.id')
    ->order_by('votes','desc')
    ->find_all();
```

This will give all pictures sorted by number of votes as result.